# Unity can't put sound to inspector field

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine

I have sound source and my question is how can I play that sound when my cube hit a wall?
My code:

```
usingUnityEngine;
usingSystem.Collections;

public class sound : MonoBehaviour {

public AudioSource soundEffect;

voidOnTriggerEnter (Collider other) 
{
   if(other.gameObject.tag == "wall")
   {
      soundEffect.Play ();
   }
}
}
```

I can't assign audio source to script in inspector. I can't put my `*.mp3` file to field.

What to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you add an audio source to the cube and place the file in Resources you can do this whenever you want to play the audio

```
GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("audioFile");
GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
```

this is in C#

Comment: thank you, but I have my own mp3 source file and I need to play it every time when my cube hit the wall. How can I do it? :)